# Open taskpane from Button click

Tags: javascript, c#, ms-word, office-js

Is it possible to open a task pane in a Word Online add-in by clicking a button in 
another task pane?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is not supported in yet. please [upvote the request in user voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15114417-support-for-hiding-showing-task-pane-through-the-o).